# mapquest geocoding - i can not get the (lon,lat) returned from the API

Tags: geocoding, request, mapquest

I just started using the mapQuest Geocoding API and I created a code for searching addresses.
The following code alerts "OK" but I can not alert the (lat, lon) coords, even I tried with so many different ways.
Can you spot what is wrong? Does this means that the coords are not actually returned?
The alerts about the coords are not even alert "undifined"...

Thanks

the code :

```
function codeAddress(){
    var ad = document.getElementById("address");//get input from form
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",                
                url: "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=Fmjtd******&outFormat=json&inFormat=json&json={location:"+ad+",options:{maxResults:1}}",                                              success: function(response) {
                    alert("OK");//alerts OK, but NONE of the followinng
                    alert(response.results[0].locations[0].location.street);
                    alert(response.results[0].locations[0].location.latLng.lat);
                    alert(response.results[0].latLng.lat);
                    alert(response.results[0].location.latLng.lat);
                    alert(responce.results[0].locations[0].latLng);

                    }})
}

//this is the html form    
<input id="address" type="textbox">    
<input type="button" value="Encode" onClick="codeAddress()">
```

Answer (score 1):

For Mapquest Geocoding you need to send the format

In the example given you get the full

Take this example and add YOUR_API_KEY

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=renderOptions&outFormat=json&inFormat=json&json={location:{street:%22Lancaster,PA%22},options:{thumbMaps:false,maxResults:1}}
```

You should be getting the flowing back

```
Country: US State: PA County: Lancaster City: Lancaster Response Code:A5XAX Lat: 40.03804 Lng: -76.30127
```

Note: 
Response Code:A5XAX shows the accuracy

thumbMaps needs to set to `false` - you only want the info - not the map.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be like

> alert(response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat);

It is that easy. I feel so humilated. I think I should stop coffee for a while...